# Efficiency of transforming counts to percentages and index scores

Tags: r

I currently have the following code that produces the desired results I want (`Data_Index` and `Data_Percentages`)

```
Input_Data <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/881843/RPubsData/gd/2010_pop_estimates.csv", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
Input_Data <- data.frame(head(Input_Data))

Rows <-nrow(Input_Data)
Vars <-ncol(Input_Data) - 1

#Total population column
TotalCount <- Input_Data[1]

#Total population sum
TotalCountSum  <- sum(TotalCount)
Input_Data[1]  <- NULL
VarNames       <- colnames(Input_Data)
Data_Per_Row   <- c()
Data_Index_Row <- c()

for (i in 1:Rows) {

    #Proportion of all areas population found in this row
    OAPer <- TotalCount[i, ] / TotalCountSum * 100

    Data_Per_Col   <- c()
    Data_Index_Col <- c()

    for(u in 1:Vars) {
        # For every column value in the selected row 
        # the percentage of that value compared to the 
        # total population (TotalCount) for that row is calculated
        VarPer <- Input_Data[i, u] / TotalCount[i, ] * 100

        # Once the percentage is calculated the index 
        # score is calculated by diving this percentage 
        # by the proportion of the total population in that 
        # area compared to all areas
        VarIndex <- VarPer / OAPer * 100

        # Binds results for all columns in the row
        Data_Per_Col   <- cbind(Data_Per_Col, VarPer)
        Data_Index_Col <- cbind(Data_Index_Col, VarIndex)
    }

    # Binds results for completed row with previously completed rows
    Data_Per_Row   <- rbind(Data_Per_Row, Data_Per_Col) 
    Data_Index_Row <- rbind(Data_Index_Row, Data_Index_Col) 
}
colnames(Data_Per_Row)   <- VarNames
colnames(Data_Index_Row) <- VarNames

# Changes the index scores to range from -1 to 1
OldRange   <- (max(Data_Index_Row) - min(Data_Index_Row))  
NewRange   <- (1 - -1)  
Data_Index <- (((Data_Index_Row - min(Data_Index_Row)) * NewRange) / OldRange) + -1
Data_Percentages <- Data_Per_Row

# Final outputs
Data_Index
Data_Percentages
```

The problem I have is that the code is very slow. I want to be able to use it on dataset that has 200,000 rows and 200 columns (which using the code at present will take around 4 days). I am sure there must be a way of speeding this process up, but I am not sure how exactly.

What the code is doing is taking (in this example) a population counts table divided into age bands and by different areas and turning it into percentages and index scores. Currently there are 2 loops so that every value in all the rows and columns are selected individually have calculations performed on them. I assume it is these loops that is making it run slow, are there any alternatives that produce the same results, but quicker? Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: you should comment your code to explain what each part is doing (even more why you're doing what you're doing). Not many people would have the patience to run your code step by step to determine what you've intended it to do. And it is good practice.

Comment: Sorry, I have added comments which (hopefully) explain what the code is doing

Comment: (+1) much better. you can wrap the comments in many lines so that it's easier to read. But it is relatively much better already to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your entire code. The for-loop is not necessary. And so is `apply`. The division can be implemented by diving a matrix entirely.

```
df <- Input_Data

total_count <- df[, 1]
total_sum   <- sum(total_count)

df <- df[, -1]

# equivalent of your for-loop
oa_per <- total_count/total_sum * 100
Data_Per_Row <- df/matrix(rep(total_count, each=5), ncol=5, byrow=T)*100
Data_Index_Row <- Data_Per_Row/oa_per * 100
names(Data_Per_Row) <- names(Data_Index_Row) <- names(df)

# rest of your code: identical
OldRange = max(Data_Index_Row) - min(Data_Index_Row)
NewRange = (1 - -1)
Data_Index = (((Data_Index_Row - min(Data_Index_Row)) * NewRange) / OldRange) + -1
Data_Percentages <- Data_Per_Row
```

Answer (score 0):

get rid of the "i" loop
use apply to calculate OAPer

```
 OAPer<-apply(TotalCount,1,
                   function(x,tcs)x/tcs*100,
                   tcs = TotalCountSum)
```

Likewise, you can vectorize the work inside the "u" loop as well, would appreciate some comments in your code