# Size of dataset causing calculation errors

Tags: r, error-handling, dataset, limit

I have modified this code below from a [previous question I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631548/efficiency-of-transforming-counts-to-percentages-and-index-scores):

```
Input_Data <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58164604/Input_Data.csv", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

TPop<-Input_Data[1]
TPopCount <- TPop[, 1]
TPopSum <- sum(TPopCount)

OACRaw<-Input_Data[,4:ncol(Input_Data)]
OACRawCount <-ncol(OACRaw)

OA_Percentage <- TPopCount/TPopSum * 100
Data_Per_Row <- OACRaw/matrix(rep(TPopCount, each=OACRawCount), ncol=OACRawCount, byrow=T)*100
Data_Index_Row <- Data_Per_Row/OA_Percentage * 100
names(Data_Per_Row) <- names(Data_Index_Row) <- names(OACRaw)
```

However, when I try and get it to work for a larger dataset (186 columns and over 180,000 rows) it gives the following error:

```
Error in FUN(left, right) : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

However when the same code is run a smaller dataset (46 columns and 180,00 rows) it works fine:

```
Input_Data <- read.csv("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58164604/Input_Data.csv", row.names=1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

TPop<-Input_Data[1]
TPopCount <- TPop[, 1]
TPopSum <- sum(TPopCount)

OACRaw<-Input_Data[,4:50]
OACRawCount <-ncol(OACRaw)

OA_Percentage <- TPopCount/TPopSum * 100
Data_Per_Row <- OACRaw/matrix(rep(TPopCount, each=OACRawCount), ncol=OACRawCount, byrow=T)*100
Data_Index_Row <- Data_Per_Row/OA_Percentage * 100
names(Data_Per_Row) <- names(Data_Index_Row) <- names(OACRaw)
```

Can anyone explain why this is and how I can get this code to work on a larger dataset? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some strange values in your `OACRaw` data frame. For example, at the 184th column, row 22, the value is a backtick character : "`". It is the cause of the error when you then try to divide it.

There may be other bogus values after the 184th column.

So the error is not due to the size of the data, just to the fact that when you select only the first columns, the bogus values are excluded.

Comment: Thanks for finding what the problem was. Not sure how I missed it.